# Error when using GUID with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My SQL table contains an Id column which is of datatype `uniqueidentifier`. As per advice found on SO, I've set it to have a default value of  `(newid())` .

Using Entity Framework 4.2 with code first, I've then mapped my Guid property to the relevant field in SQL:

```
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

However, whenever I try to insert an entity I receive the following exception:

> The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity.
>
> The argument types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 61.

The only solution I can find on both here and Google is to add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` as a data annotation on my Id. This doesn't change a thing - so what else could be causing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Siva. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this doesn't apply to my situation as I'm using code first which doesn't use a .edmx file.

Comment: Have you tried setting the guid to nullable i.e. `guid?` it will have a default valud of guid.Empty ({00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}) and EF may be trying to insert this value as it is not null.

Comment: Show the code causing the issue and create script for your database table.

Answer (score 1):

have you try set identify StoreGeneratedPattern ?
you could do it in OnModelCreate Method.

```
Model.Entity<Foo>().Property(o => o.Id).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've put the following in my OnModelCreating method but I'm still having the same issue. Does it matter that I'm setting it using the modelBuilder?

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(o => o.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Comment: Yes. using modelBuilder.
I noticed you have different error, could you show the code causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Using a Guid as a primary key is ill-advised if you need performance and have an index over it. The Guids are being generated with randomized values, so every time you insert a new item it will cause more work for SQL to update the index than if you used a bigint (it has to insert into different parts of the index each time instead of always appending to the end). If you need a unique identifier (such as to link items across systems that don't share the same database) then simply add it as an additional column on the table (and if you are paranoid and willing to take a perf hit on insert/update, you could additionally add a unique constraint over it).